# Checking alert dialog validation

Tags: java, android

I have set alert dialog on textview's `onclicklistener`, and there I have added some items using array adapter. Now what I want to do is check if the user selects an item from the alert dialog and clicks on <kbd>submit</kbd>. It should submit, otherwise not. But as per my `if` I select or not it displays message fill the details.

```
 boolean isSetDay = false;
 sp3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.daydates);
 btnsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreg);

 final String[] items = new String[] {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};
 adapter123 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);


 sp3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View w) {
      new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistrationForm.this)
      .setTitle("Select Day")
      .setAdapter(adapter123, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            sp3.setText(adapter123.getItem(which).toString());
            isSetDay=true;

          dialog.dismiss();
        }
      }).create().show();
    }
  });
     btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) 
 {
    if(emailtext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 &&   passtext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && confirmpass.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && username.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && firstname.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && lastname.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && isSetDay==true && isSetMonth==true &&    isSetYear==true && isSetPro==true)
{
isSetDay=false;
isSetMonth=false;
isSetYear=false;
isSetPro=false;
new AttemptLogin().execute();


}

  else
 {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill the details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
  break;
 }
 });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please pay attention to formatting.
The code as you posted is hard to read,
and not pleasant to review.

Most notably, the indentation is inconsistent or sometimes random,
and you have very long horizontal lines forcing readers to scroll.
For example this one:

> ```
> if(emailtext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 &&   passtext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && confirmpass.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && username.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && firstname.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && lastname.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && isSetDay==true && isSetMonth==true &&    isSetYear==true && isSetPro==true)
> ```

Broken up to multiple lines it becomes a lot easier to read:

```
    if (emailtext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
            && passtext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
            && confirmpass.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
            && username.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
            && firstname.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
            && lastname.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
            && isSetDay == true
            && isSetMonth == true
            && isSetYear == true
            && isSetPro == true)
```

Note that using `== true` with boolean expressions is really pointless,
as you could use the expressions directly:
`if (something) { ... }` is exactly the same as 
`if (something == true) { ... }`.
So you could drop all the `== true` from the above.

When checking if a string is empty, instead of `str.length() > 0`,
a better way is `!str.isEmpty()`.

To avoid code duplication of `.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()` it would be a good idea to add a helper function:

```
private boolean notEmpty(EditText input) {
    return !input.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty();
}
```

So that you can rewrite the condition in the `if` like this:

```
    if (notEmpty(emailtext)
            && notEmpty(passtext)
            && notEmpty(confirmpass)
            && notEmpty(username)
            && notEmpty(firstname)
            && notEmpty(lastname)
            && isSetDay
            && isSetMonth
            && isSetYear
            && isSetPro)
```

Even better, as [@hkj](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/27975/h-j-k) suggested,
the `notEmpty` method could take varargs:

```
private boolean notEmpty(EditText ... args) {
    for (EditText input : args) {
        if (input.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

which will allow you to shorten the condition even more:

```
    if (notEmpty(emailtext, passtext, confirmpass, username, firstname, lastname)
            && isSetDay
            && isSetMonth
            && isSetYear
            && isSetPro)
```

This line is also too long, and also error-prone to type it:

> ```
> final String[] items = new String[] {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};
> ```

It would be better to fill this array programmatically, for example:

```
    final String[] items = new String[31];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        items[i] = String.format("%02d", i + 1);
    }
```

Comment: How about `varags` for that nifty `notEmpty()` method? :)

Comment: @h.j.k. now *that* would be really nifty ;-) Good tip, thanks, updated my post.

Comment: @Heslacher I don't have an Android dev env here to verify, but I think it's needed. Are you really sure it's not? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()

Comment: oops, I only read java, so no you are right

Comment: @Heslacher I thought so, and yeah, it's a real bummer eh ;)